# Unity: how to solve Firebase.Storage.StorageException?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

i'm trying to use firebase storage to upload images.
and here is what I've tried.

```
 public void firetalk(string path)
        {

            Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

            Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://<myurl>.appspot.com/");

            Firebase.Storage.StorageReference art_image_ref = storage_ref.Child("images/innocence.jpg");

            art_image_ref.PutFileAsync(path).ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                }
                else
                {
                    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
                    Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);
                }
            });
        }
```

the firetalk funtion recieves a path and i use `PutFileAsync` for using the upload using path ,however i'm getting this error..

```
System.AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.
-----------------
Firebase.Storage.StorageException: Permission denied. Could not perform this operation
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GracesGames.SimpleFileBrowser.Scripts.explorer_script:m__0(Task`1) (at Assets/scripts/explorer_script.cs:85)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1:SetException(Exception)
Firebase.Storage.StorageReference:CompleteTask(Task`1, TaskCompletionSource`1, Func`1, String, Boolean)
Firebase.Storage.c__AnonStorey6:<>m__0(Task`1)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1:SetException(Exception)
Firebase.Storage.c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0()
Firebase.Storage.Future_StorageMetadata:SWIG_CompletionDispatcher(Int32)
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseAppUtils:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update()
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update()
```

any gueses?

Comment: You should include your firestore security rules.

Comment: @AndréKool how? in the security rules i have service 
`firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Your rules states that you need to be authenticated. That's the reason you are getting the permission denied.